# External HDD disconnects whenever computer try to access any files

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Connected via USB through separately bought docking station
Used to work, but now disconnects whenever trying to access any file including loading of thumbnails.
Opening empty folders are ok, but if any thumbnails are loaded into folder view, it will disconnect.

HDD also disconnects (With the USB disconnecting sound) when windows automatically tries to scan for files when connecting new USB storage device.
After a few seconds, HDD will connect again (with sound).

After many disconnects and reconnects, the drive remains visible in My Computer even when I pull out the cable. It won't disappear until I do a hard restart. Computer will be stuck at "Shutting Down" unless I do a hard restart.

I had another docking station which I replaced when this begun to happen. 2 HDDs, same symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

So, this problem happened across two docking stations and two different hard drives?  What are the common factors in this situation?

- The install of your Operating System?
- Your motherboard?
- Your power supply?

... and you need to continue this list.  Why?  Because you need to identify what is common before you start to eliminate them.

Now, I'm guessing that the issue is the install of Windows, because you say "the drive remains visible in My Computer even when I pull out the cable. It won't disappear until I do a hard restart. Computer will be stuck at "Shutting Down" unless I do a hard restart." so what I would do is obtain a copy of a Linux LiveCD (like [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com) for example), boot to it, and see if the docking station works normally then... or try the docking station on a different computer running Windows.